# Add HTTPS support to Icecast2 using Let's Encrypt

Tags: apache2, lets-encrypt, icecast

I have an Icecast2 server running on the default port `8000` and I want to add HTTPs support to it with a free Let's Encrypt certificate. For example:

- `http://example.com:8000/test.mp3` (current)
- `https://example.com/test.mp3` (desired)

I've seen that Icecast2 supports SSL internally but that option is not available in some (most?) GNU/Linux distributions. Moreover I see that using the internal SSL support is not very integrated with Let's Encrypt since you have to concatenate the two certificates into a single files.

https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/config-file.html

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/icecast2-and-letsencrypt/9329

**Question**: What are the suggested ways to add `https://` support to Icecast2 with Let's Encrypt?

For example using the official [icecast2 package from Debian GNU/Linux stable](https://packages.debian.org/stable/icecast2) and without compiling anything. Note that on the server I already have the webserver Apache HTTPd (`apache2`) running, listening on port `80` and `443`. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Do you have native SSL support in your icecast2 package?

If you love to use the official package, first check if you have SSL support in your already installed `icecast2` package:

```
ldd /usr/bin/icecast2 | grep ssl
```

If you don't see anything, you have **no** native support for SSL. In this case you can choose one of these options:

- Option `A`: remove the package and install something else
- Option `B`: setup a frontend webserver using nginx
- Option `C`: setup a frontend webserver using Apache (← this answer)

### How to use Apache to setup a frontend webserver with HTTPs support, to serve Icecast2

To visit Icecast over `https://`, you can install Apache and use it as frontend webserver, listening on standard port `443`. It's easy to use Let's Encrypt to create a free certificate for Apache. Once it works, you can pass the traffic to Icecast2.

```
 Browser
 │
 │ https://example.com/radio.mp3
 ▼
┌───────────┐
│           │
│ Apache    │:443
│           │
└┬──────────┘
 │
 │ http://localhost:8080/radio.mp3
 ▼
┌───────────┐
│           │
│ Icecast   │:8080
│           │
└───────────┘
```

If you use Debian GNU/Linux, here the guide:

- https://wiki.debian.org/Icecast2

The core of the solution is to enable an apache VirtualHost like this:

```
#
# Apache VirtualHost serving my Icecast under HTTPs (:443)
#
# This frontend webserver passes all the traffic to
# the underlying Icecast, listening on port 8000.
#
# The certificate comes from Let's Encrypt.
#
# Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71383133/3451846
<virtualhost *:443>

  ServerName example.com

  # this path is not useful and it's used only for Let's Encrypt's temporary files during the renewal process
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  # send all traffic to Icecast in plaintext
  <Location "/">
    ProxyPass        http://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000/
  </Location>

  # these files are served from /var/www/html to serve Let's Encrypt temporary files
  <Location "/.well-known/acme-challenge">
    ProxyPass !
  </Location>

  <IfFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
  </IfFile>

</virtualhost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com

  Redirect / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

And then enable it and issue your certificate:

```
letsencrypt certonly --domain example.com --webroot --webroot-path /var/www/html
```

But this is explained maybe better from the above guide.

At the moment the guide does not cover `nginx` but other answers might give a similar practical example using that technology as well as `apache2`. The benefit of involving a frontend webserver like `apache2` or `nginx` is that you don't have to touch Icecast. Also, it allows to serve Icecast2 among your already-existing websites, if any.

---

Other answers might want to talk about an Icecast2's native interface with Let's Encrypt. At the moment I can share just the `apache2` method that is the one I use in production since years without any problem. Moreover since I use Debian GNU/Linux, my package has not SSL support.

Comment: Hi @Brad. Thank you. What is your method for integrating it with Let's Encrypt then? It seems to me that it does not read Let's Encrypt's native format. But there is a conversion to be done at each renewal. I think your solution deserves an additional answer if you have details. I will upvote.

Comment: Hi @Brad I've tried your approach but in Debian GNU/Linux as well as in Ubuntu the Icecast2 package is not compiled with SSL support. I tried to improve this answer to explain why I was not able to use your solution. If I'm wrong or you happen to have a method to use native support I'll put +1 to your answer. Thank you so much Brad.

Comment: Hi @Brad your comment is now integrated in the answer. In this case StackOverflow suggests to remove our comment. Please remove your comments, then mark also my comments as "It's no longer needed." so I will be removed as well. Thanks